# Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Tags: java

I have two issues on the same line the first is

```
Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Error: Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
```

I have no idea why its telling me that error, the noob mode is kicking in right now so I cant figure it out.

```
import java.awt.*;//for graphics class
import java .util.*;// for scanner class
//start of class
public class bouncingball {
     // public static final int CENTER = 300;


      //start of main
      public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("Project 2 modified by Jordan Spicer");

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 400);

        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ball(g);
        int test = 0;
        String colors = "";
        System.out.println(" this program prints out a bouncing ball");


       System.out.println("please pick a color for the ball either red or blue ");

        colors = input.nextLine();

        if( (colors.compareTo("blue") == 0) ||colors.compareTo("red") == 0){

        System.out.println("that wasnt a good color try again only put red or blue");

          colors = input.nextLine();
          System.out.println(colors);

        }       
        else{
          System.out.println(colors);


        }

        public static void ball (Graphics g){ <======= the errors are at this line here
          g.setcolor(Color.RED);
       g.drawcircle(50,50,50,50);



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If you at least **indent** your code, you could have spotted the error and saved a question post.

Comment: 1) your code formatting is bad, terrible really, making it hard for others to read your code. When asking help from volunteers here, we greatly appreciate your putting in just a little effort to make your code presentable and readable. 2) you're doing your Swing drawing incorrectly, as you shouldn't be getting your Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. The object obtained this way is short lived, and so your drawing is at risk of disappearing. Instead read the Swing painting tutorials to see the right way to draw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you method inside another method. Move it to outside. Move following method declarationt to outside.

```
public static void ball (Graphics g){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little rusty with java right now, but I don't think you can have the method

```
public static void ball (Graphics g)
```

inside of the main method. Try declaring it before the main method?